# Dynamic_Featured_Image with theme added image crop

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-featured-image

Im using the plugin "Dynamic_Featured_Image" for wordpress. I can get the image to show all the default image sizes (full/medium/thumb), but I want it to use a custom added one in my theme.

```
<?php
    if( class_exists('Dynamic_Featured_Image') )
    {
        global $dynamic_featured_image;
        $featured_images = $dynamic_featured_image->get_featured_images();

        $i = 0;
        foreach ($featured_images as $row=>$innerArray)
        {
            $id = $featured_images[$i]['attachment_id'];

            $mediumSizedImage = $dynamic_featured_image->get_image_url($id,'conferance'); 
            $caption = $dynamic_featured_image->get_image_caption( $mediumSizedImage );

            echo "      <li><img src=\"".$mediumSizedImage."\" alt=\"".$caption."\"><div class=\"captionText\">".$caption."&nbsp;</div></li>";

            $i++;
        }
    }
?>
```

And the themesupported thumb is:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_image_size( 'conferance', 570, 335, true );
```

But when I fetch the image it still comes in the full (original size). Any clues why?

Comment: Have you tried a `var_dump($featured_images);`? What is the output?

Comment: var_dump only returns full and thumb:

array(2) {
[0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["thumb"]=>
    string(68) "http://link-to-image.jpg"
    ["full"]=>
    string(68) "http://link-to-image.jpg"
    ["attachment_id"]=>
    string(3) "556"
  }
}

Comment: But when I read about (almost) the same issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24843444/medium-size-image-by-plugin-called-dynamic-featured-image) you can get the medium (standard) size. So I think there should be a way to get the theme added custom crop sizes.

Comment: As you can see here: https://github.com/ankitpokhrel/Dynamic-Featured-Image/wiki/API-Functions#3-get_image_url-attachment_id-size--full- 'medium' is one of the standard values allowed by this plugin. It doesn't seem to support custom sizes as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working as expected. Looks like you added the new image size `conferance` after uploading the images. WordPress doesn't regenerate the newly registered size, it only applies it to the future uploads. Please refer this [thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74229/auto-resize-images-after-adding-a-new-size).